# Is it possible to measure the sound intensity from PCM data?

Tags: audio, stm32, pcm

I am using two **PDM microphones**(mems transducer) with **STM32** to measure the intensity and if the intensity of the left microphone is higher than the right one then an LED should turn on.

We measure the intensity of analog signals like when the signal is higher than a certain threshold then do something(if(ADC_Val >= 3000)do something...), so is it possible to do such things with PDM microphones?

Is it possible to measure the intensity of sound from **PCM samples**?

Comment: What is the exact problem? if you can sample from input, you can do what you want. first of all, try to sample the input.